# ¿ Como puedo acomodar la siguiente consulta con laravel 5.7 Query Builder?

Tags: postgresql, eloquent

Esta es la consulta que quiero pasar a Query Builder, pero me perdí en la parte final donde tengo el where y like, me pueden ayudar...

```
// select conector.description from conector inner join
// modelo on(modelo."idConec"=conector.id) inner join
// marca on(marca."idConec"=conector.id) inner join
// producto on(producto.id=modelo."idProd") and (producto.id=marca."idProd")
// where marca.description like '%w%' AND modelo.description like '%2%';

 $users = DB::table('conector.description')
  ->join('modelo', 'modelo."idProd"', '=', 'conector.id')
  ->join('marca', 'marca."idProd"', '=', 'conector.id')
  ->join('producto', 'producto.id', '=', 'modelo."idProd"')
  ->AND('producto.id', '=', 'marca."idProd"')
  ->where('marca', 'marca.description', 'orders.price')
  ->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que estás usando no es Eloquent, sino [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries). Solo una pequeña aclaración... Ahora si vamos al código!

**Query original:**

```
// select conector.description from conector inner join
// modelo on(modelo."idConec"=conector.id) inner join
// marca on(marca."idConec"=conector.id) inner join
// producto on(producto.id=modelo."idProd") and (producto.id=marca."idProd")
// where marca.description like '%w%' AND modelo.description like '%2%';
```

**Conversión a Query Builder:**

```
$users = DB::table('conector') // Aquí va el nombre de la tabla, NO el campo.
      ->join('modelo', 'conector.id', '=', 'modelo.idConec')
      ->join('marca', 'conector.id', '=', 'modelo.idConec')
      ->join('producto', function ($join) {
            $join->on('modelo.idProd', '=', 'producto.id')
                 ->orOn('marca.idProd', '=', 'producto.id');
        })
      ->where([
                ['marca.description ', 'like', '%w%'],
                ['subscribed', 'like', '%2%'],
             ])
      ->select('conector.description')
      ->get();
```

Como podrás ver, en el `WHERE` le paso las condiciones como un array, ya que en este caso por lo menos, no hay agrupamiento de condiciones por lo que no hay inconvenientes y es mas legible. Se deben cumplir TODAS las condiciones. Puedes leer la [documentación (where-clauses)](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#where-clauses) para comprender mejor el funcionamiento. En dicha documentacion tambien podras ver que puedes usar `"like", "=", "<", ">", "<>"` entre otros.

Un pequeño detalle, yo nunca trabaje con PostgreSQL pero generalmente por convención, los nombres de las tablas deberías ponerlos en plural.

**Editado:** Incorporo el uso de [Advanced Join Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#joins) para relacionar la tabla "producto".

Comment: Igual a ti muchas gracias por la explicacion pero el mismo problema tengo al momento de hacer los joins me marca error, probe con where, and, ',' pero no me funciona

Es justo en los joins:




          ->join('producto', 'modelo.idProd', '=', 'producto.id')
          ->join('producto', 'marca.idProd', '=', 'producto.id')



Y el error es: PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42712]: Duplicate alias: 7 ERROR: table name "producto" specified more than once")

Comment: Ya está editada la respuesta para reemplazar ese join. Podrías probar?

Comment: Me funciono de maravilla, muchas gracias !!!

solo el subscribed lo cambie por 'modelo.description ', 'like', '%2%' ya que me marcaba error,   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42703]: Undefined column: 7 ERROR:  column "subscribed" does not exist
LINE 1: ...d" where ("marca"."description"::text like $1 and "subscribe...

Comment: buenísimo..de nada, Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Una opción es usar el método `where()` y pasar por dentro múltiples condiciones, además de usar el nombre del modelo, por que al momento que llamas al facade `\DB` estas usando pero el query Builder

Tu consulta debería verse así

```
$data = ModeName::
         select('conector.description')
         ->join('modelo', 'modelo."idProd"', '=', 'conector.id')
         ->join('marca', 'marca."idProd"', '=', 'conector.id')
         ->join('producto', 'producto.id', '=', 'modelo."idProd"')
         ->where([
                 ['marca.description ', 'like', '%w%'],
                         ['subscribed', 'like', '%2%'],
            ])->get();
```

O también existe la posibilidad de que hagas un

```
WHERE condicion1 AND condicion 2
```

dentro de Laravel pero de este modo

```
->where('condicion1')
->where('condicion2')
```

Con el uso de un doble `where`

```
$data = ModeName::
             select('conector.description')
             ->join('modelo', 'modelo."idProd"', '=', 'conector.id')
             ->join('marca', 'marca."idProd"', '=', 'conector.id')
             ->join('producto', 'producto.id', '=', 'modelo."idProd"')
             ->where(condicion1)
             ->where(condicion2)
             ->get();
```

Recuerda para que consideres que estas usando a Eloquent debería notarse que estas usando el nombre del Modelo en tu consulta

Comment: Hola, gracias por la explicación, probé la consulta y casi funciona pero me marca error al momento de hacer esta instrucción:



 ->join('producto', 'modelo.idProd', '=', 'producto.id')
 ->join('producto', 'marca.idProd', '=', 'producto.id')


El error es el siguiente:


PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42712]: Duplicate alias: 7 ERROR:  table name "producto" specified more than once")
      C:\Telegram\CONNECT\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:330